# Controlling back key press in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my application on pressing back key, I get message box which is working correctly as expected showing the message box and in the back ground app is running, and ok pressing ok/cancel app behaves normally.

Once the message box is there, and again I press back key, the message box should disappear and if I again press back key it should come back again unless I choose ok/cancel.

I am not able to perform the above functionality, on pressing second time back button, message box is not going off.

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)

{

    CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
    {
         Caption = "Would you like to terminate the transfer?",
         //Message = "",
         LeftButtonContent = "Ok",
         RightButtonContent = "Cancel"
    };
    messageBox.show();

messageBox.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>

{

switch (e1.Result)

{

            case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                //exiting the current transfer happening
                break;
            case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
                // do nothing here
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
messageBox.show();

}
```

Now the problem is everytime back key is as follows:

Current O/P: On pressing back key again and again, message box pop up.

Desired O/P: If I press back key once, message box should pop up, if I press again it should go off without disturbing the background transfer and this should happen on pressing back key again and again unless you choose an option from message box.

Kindly help me in controlling message box display.

Comment: You're going to have to provide the code you are using in order for us to help you identify the issue.

Comment: I have provided the code in the answer, kindly check as i was not able to post full code here.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        MessageBox.Show("C#");
    }
```

Basic implemintation:

```
bool OnOff = true;

        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

            e.Cancel = true;

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (this.OnOff)
                {
                    CustomMessageBox message = new CustomMessageBox
                    {
                        Caption = "Would you like to terminate the transfer?",
                        LeftButtonContent = "Ok",
                        RightButtonContent = "Cancel"
                    };

                    message.Dismissed += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        ((CustomMessageBox)sender).Dismissing += (o, eventArgs) => eventArgs.Cancel = true;

                        if (args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton)
                        {
                            // Code
                        }
                        else if (args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton)
                        {
                            // Code
                        }
                    };

                    message.Show();

                    this.OnOff = false;
                }
                else
                    this.OnOff = true;

            });
        }
```

Here you can find more information: [Using the CustomMessageBox in OnBackKeyPressed](http://metronuggets.com/2013/06/11/using-the-custommessagebox-in-onbackkeypressed/)

Comment: Hi Roman, 
kindly check the code in the answers and suggest me how i should go about.

Comment: @Simrandeep Singh The implementation is in the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Simrandeep Singh Can you mark my answer as answer of your question? Thanks.

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh: as per the above request 2.5 years ago, would you accept this answer? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so that it turns green. This is how we thank people for their efforts, and how we mark a question as resolved. Thanks.